# Linq to Entities query returns duplicate results

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

So I queried a mapped view (which has no primary key, it's a view) and my results had duplicates.  I pulled the sql query from the linq execution and ran it on the db, no duplicates.  What gives!
Any help would be great!

Comment: Thanks for finding a duplicate post.  I guess wrong search terms.

Answer (score 0):

Even though there is no primary key in your view, a combination of the columns should be unique. In your Entity Data Model, make those columns the Entity Key. Now your query should return the correct result